# jstl <select> to persist selection

Tags: struts2, jstl

I have a JSP page where am printing the arraylist content via an iterator

```
<s:iterator var="BeanList" value="BeanList">
    <option value='<s:property value="#BeanList.simpleID"/>'>
        <s:property value="#BeanList.simpleText" />
    </option>
</s:iterator>
```

Every time the user selects an option, the form submits to the action handling. I want to be able to take the value of the clicked option, and when the page is reloaded after the submit, the same value persists in the select drop down.

Any help will be greatly apprecaited,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `HTML Select` Tag, with values populated from `Struts2 Property` Tag.

No JSTL is involved.

But believe me, you can avoid this using the `Struts2 Select` Tag directly.

Official documentation: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/select.html

In Action

```
@Getter @Setter List<String> allCities; 
@Getter @Setter String selectedCity;
```

In JSP:

```
<s:select list="allCities" 
          name="selectedCity" />
```

Faster and cleaner than iterating manually :)

---

Eventually you can add an optional header value:

```
<s:select list="allCities" 
          name="selectedCity" 
          headerKey="-1" 
          headerValue="Select a City" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to declare a variable with select box name in Action class, and put setter and getter for that. And then, when you are submitting the form, the name matches and it automatically populate in Action class.

When retrieving the data set `value` to same variable.Then it will populate automatically by using name.

This will happen by using `params interceptor` internally.